# How to rename the time series that existed data in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: rename, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask, if I need to rename the name of time series that existed data, can Apache IoTDB do this and how to achieve this? Anyone can list out the steps that I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

his efficiency of this progress may be limited by the amount of data in Apache IoTDBYou can use `export` to export the data under this time series, and then change the time series name using `sed`, finally using `import` to import the original data. This efficiency of this progress may be limited by the amount of data,his efficiency of this progress may be limited by the amount of data in Apache IoTDB, so you can give it a try.

Comment: Does that mean changing/replacing the name in files using sed, but no inbuilt command to rename ?